# What does "affect at work" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

What does *affect at work* mean?

Does it mean that something affects someone at work, or that someone is pretending something at work?

Comment: Can you provide some more context please?  Eg the whole phrase or piece of text where this comes from?

Comment: It should be noted that "affect" has an entirely different meaning in psychology.

Comment: According to the 29000+ results on Google, "affect at work" means "mood at work".

Answer (score 1):

[Affect](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/affect) means to cause a change in something:

> 1. To act upon; to produce an effect or change upon; as, cold affects the body; loss affects our interests.
>
> ---
>
> [The American Dictionary of the English language by Noah Webster, 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/affect)

So literally speaking, "affect someone at work" would mean to change the way they are at their job. However, the typical usage of these words is closer to the meaning of "poorly affects someone at work" and implies that whatever is affecting them, is affecting them in a way that worsens their job performance, as in these exemplary quotations:

> An employee's personal life is his own business, unless it affects his job performance. Then the supervisor should intervene, but only to the extent necessary to get the job performance back to par, and then he should withdraw.
>
> ---
>
> [Page 342 of Managing the Patient-Focused Laboratory by George G. Ludenberg and published by Medical Economics Co., Book Division in 1975](https://books.google.com/books?id=rx8EAQAAIAAJ&q=%22it+affects+his+job%22&dq=%22it+affects+his+job%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicm-75_MLOAhVY42MKHc2UAYgQ6AEITTAJ)

In that case, we know it's a bad affect because the employer feels compelled to do something he should not normally do. I also can not imagine anything good coming of the next case:

> Monday, February 1st Howard made the comment to me "I am so sexually frustrated by you I think I am going to get you fired." This has not been the first time these remarks have been made ... however, I do not want to be involved in ANY problems such as this. I will admit it has greatly affected my job performance.
>
> ---
>
> [Denning-Boyles v. WCES, INC. Annotate this Case 473 S.E.2d 38 (1996)](http://law.justia.com/cases/north-carolina/court-of-appeals/1996/coa94-1231-1.html)

There is no strict rule against using the word "affect" meaning a change for the better, but in most contexts we would usually prefer the word "[improve](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/improve)" to concisely signify that the change in performance is in fact better:

> 1. To make better; to advance in value or good qualities. We amend a bad, but improve a good thing.
>
> A good education improves the mind and the manners. A judicious rotation of crops tends to improve land.
>
> ---
>
> [The American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster, 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/improve)

Answer (score 0):

"affect" has several meanings: one is similar to "mood" or "level of happiness/sadness".

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/affect#nav3

It may be referring to that, eg how work affects people's happiness.  If you provided some context we wouldn't need to guess.